# A relativity paradox

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, reference-frames, observers

Imagine a train moving in constant velocity (inertial frame), a person sitting in the train and a charged particle stationary in relative to the person. This person sees the particle has an electric field (and no magnetic field).

Now, an observer who is in a train station, sees the particle in the train, has an electric field and a magnetic field (a moving charged particle, generates magnetic field).

How can we explain this paradox?

Answer (score 2):

There is no paradox. The electric and magnetic fields do not transform like vectors under Lorentz boosts, but rather as components of the Faraday tensor $F$. In other words,
$$E^i = F^{i0} \qquad B^i = \frac{1}{2}\epsilon^{ijk} F_{jk}$$

If some quantity $A$ transforms like a vector and $A=0$ in any coordinate system, then $A=0$ in *every* coordinate system.  This is not true of the electric and magnetic fields precisely because they do not transform as vectors.  The correct transformation laws corresponding to a Lorentz boost with velocity $\mathbf v$ relative to the original frame turn out to be

$$E'_\parallel = E_\parallel$$
$$\mathbf E_\perp' = \gamma(\mathbf E_\perp - \mathbf v \times \mathbf B)$$
$$B'_\parallel = B_\parallel$$
$$\mathbf B_\perp' = \gamma(\mathbf B_\perp + \mathbf v \times \mathbf E / c^2)$$

where $\parallel$ and $\perp$ refer to the directions parallel to and perpendicular to $\mathbf v$. As you can see, even if $\mathbf B=0$ in the stationary frame, we still obtain $\mathbf B'\neq 0 $ in the moving frame.

Comment: Thanks for your response. How can we conceptually explain moving particles measuring different electrical fields (E and E')?

Comment: @Ebi If you have two reference frames which are rotated with respect to one another, you will generally find that e.g. the $x$-components $E_x$ and $E_x'$ of the electric field are different. This isn't surprising, since a particular component of a $3$-vector is not preserved under arbitrary rotations.  Instead, we find that the components transform via the rule $E'^i = \sum_{j} R^i_{\ \ j} E^j$, where $R$ is the relevant rotation matrix.  In a precisely analogous way, if two reference frames are related by a Lorentz transformation $\Lambda$ (which may include a rotation and/or a boost) [...]

Comment: then the electric fields - whose components $E^i$ are now understood to be the $(i0)$-components of the Faraday tensor $F$ - are also not generally preserved. Instead, we find that $E'^i=F'^{i0} = \Lambda^i_{\ \ \mu} \Lambda^0_{\ \ \nu} F^{\mu\nu}$ which, after a bit of work, yields the transformation law written in my answer if $\Lambda$ corresponds to a pure boost, and reduces to the expression in my previous comment if $\Lambda$ corresponds to a pure rotation. The key point is that the EoM for a charged particle is $\dot p_\mu = qF_{\mu\nu} u^\nu$, and the splitting of $F$ into [...]

Comment: @Ebi [...] electric and magnetic contributions is frame-dependent in precisely the same way as the splitting of a 3-vector in to $x,y,$ and $z$-components is frame-dependent.